# Undoing latest push to remote branch

Tags: git, github

I accidentally committed and pushed my code changes to the wrong branch.

Here is what I have done to undo my bad changes

1. git log : find out where I need to go back to
2. git reset --hard 3cd4e57dcbb2a5bae350086c11d64c2f01ad4546
3. git push -f origin 3cd4e57dcbb2a5bae350086c11d64c2f01ad4546:develop

but I get an error

> ! [remote rejected] 3cd4e57dcbb2a5bae350086c11d64c2f01ad4546 -> develop (protected branch hook declined)

How do I undo on the remote as well? I guess git reset --hard is only local not remote.

Comment: The `remote rejected` means that they said "no" to your attempt to push.  There is therefore nothing to undo there.  If you need to do something there, you must do something *new*, not *un*-do something.

Comment: You might just do a git revert on the branch you mistakenly pushed to, see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the remote branch is protected.
To make the force-push work,
you can temporarily unprotect the branch, push, and protect again.
You can do this on the **Settings / Branches** tab of your repository's page on GitHub.
Note that this (and force-pushing in general) is not a recommended operation on public repositories.

Alternatively,
you can undo the commit by reverting it,
which will generate a new commit after the bad one,
and then simply push.

Comment: yes that was the solution. we unprotected the branch. forced the previous commit and then reprotected it. 

Now I have to walk 3 times on burning coal for committing to the wrong branch.

Answer (score 2):

I put in a comment, but this is (much) too long as a comment, so I'll put this in as an answer as well.  It's not clear to me what you have done both locally and in any other (push-able) repositories, at this point.

#### Distributed repositories

First, keep in mind that every time you use Git in a distributed manner—on your own machine, and with a "remote" like `origin`—that there are two (or more) separate Git repositories involved.  Things you do locally are, indeed, purely local: you do them in *your* repository, and now *you* have them, but no other repository has these commits.

To send commits from your repository to another, you can either *push* them:

`git push origin refspec`

or talk to whoever runs the other repository—let's say it's your friend Bob—and convince *him* to run `git fetch` to *your* repository.

When the remote is a big server like GitHub, so that you don't actually have a friend Bob running it, the server folks usually set things up so that you have some sort of interface (such as a web browser method) by which you can make changes.  For instance GitHub allows you to "pretend to be Bob" and do things like protect and unprotect branches by their name on the GitHub server.

#### The commit graph

Next, remember that branch names in Git are just treated as moveable pointers to commits in a commit graph.  The commit graph is much more permanent and solid: once a commit exists, it exists in that exact form "forever".  Branch names, however, can be added, removed, and moved around.  So it's the *commits*, which have as their "true names" those big ugly hash IDs like `3cd4e57dcbb2a5bae350086c11d64c2f01ad4546`—that are the main concern—but you almost always *access* the commits through things like branch names.

(Branch names also *protect* commits, as well as make them accessible, though for the moment that's not something you need to worry about.)

#### Draw your commit graph

These things always make more sense if you draw (at least part of) your commit graph.  You may have a branch name like `develop` that "points to" (has the ID of) a commit like `3cd4e57dcbb2a5bae350086c11d64c2f01ad4546`.  That particular commit itself, however, points to (contains the ID of) another, earlier, commit.  Every commit points back to its parent commits, and this means we can draw the linkage of commits using arrows.  I don't actually have arrows so I use approximations here:

```
... <- o <- o <- o   <-- develop
```

Here, each commit is just a round `o` pointing back to its parent.  The branch name `develop` points to the *most recent* or *tip* commit of the branch.  That commit points to its parent, which points to another parent, and so on.

All the intermediate arrows tend to be just a distraction (plus they're kind of backwards) so I prefer to draw these as:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- develop
```

If we have `develop` "branching off" from another branch like `master`, the drawing makes it pretty clear how this works:

```
...--o--o--o--o   <-- master
      \
       o--o--o    <-- develop
```

#### `git reset` moves branch labels

When you use `git reset`, it lets you move your branch *labels*.  This has no effect on the *graph* itself, only on *where the label points*.  Let's say that you are on branch `develop` and you use `git reset` to "remove" the last commit from `develop`.  The picture now changes to:

```
...--o--o--o--o   <-- master
      \
       o--o--o
          ^
          |
       develop
```

See how the graph is totally unchanged, and only the label has moved?  *The old tip of `develop`*—the commit itself, that is—is still there.  It's just that it no longer has a *branch name* pointing to it.  To name that particular commit, you now have to use its hash ID, which you may or may not have saved anywhere.

(Well, it has no such name *in this drawing*.  But did we draw in *all* the branch names?  If not, is there some *other* human-readable name that points to it?  Again, let's not worry about that for the moment.)

Before `git reset`, if you ask your Git to show you the commit you call `develop`, it shows you the old tip: the rightmost `o` commit on the line there.  After `git reset`, if you ask your Git to show you the commit you call `develop`, it shows you the middle `o` commit on that same line.  So *your* Git now thinks that `develop` means that commit and all the earlier ones.

#### `git push` asks the *other* Git to change where *its* names point

As you suggested in your question, doing the `git reset` only changes *your* Git's idea of which commit `develop` names.  Any other repository that has the name `develop` pointing to some other commit—such as the previous tip—*still* has *their* name pointing to the old tip.

Using `git push`, you can ask any other Git that you can connect-to, to change their idea of where any branch name should point.  That other Git has the right to say "no", and there are two "levels" you can use when doing `git push`: a sort of polite request, "please do this", and the more forceful "do this!" that you get with `--force`.  The other Git can still say "no" to one or both such operations.

#### What happens when you make a bad commit

You say in your question that you:

> commited and pushed my code changes to the wrong branch.

It's not clear to me whether you committed to the wrong branch, then pushed that branch by name, or whether you committed to the right branch, then pushed the wrong name, or what.  It's also not clear whether your push succeeded in the first place, since the only example output you gave has an error:

> ```
> git push -f origin 3cd4e57dcbb2a5bae350086c11d64c2f01ad4546:develop
> ! [remote rejected] 3cd4e57dcbb2a5bae350086c11d64c2f01ad4546 -> develop
> (protected branch hook declined)
> ```

This was a force-push, and they still said "no".  The error message here uses the phrase "protected branch", which is a GitHub feature, but which is also a GitLab feature, and could come from pretty much anywhere.  So I'm not sure *which* protection feature this refers to.  All I can be sure of is that they said "no", and not really *why* they said "no".  And, in particular, I cannot tell from this whether any *earlier* push succeeded.

Let's take a closer look at what happens with bad commits in either case, though.  Let's begin with this graph:

```
...--o--o--o--o   <-- master
      \
       o--o       <-- develop
```

If you're on branch `develop` and you make some changes to your work-tree and `git add` and `git commit`, Git makes a new commit with the new snapshot.  Let's say it's not a good change though, and let's call it `B` for Bad:

```
...--o--o--o--o   <-- master
      \
       o--o--B    <-- develop
```

If you *have not* pushed this anywhere, then by definition, nobody else has the bad commit.  That makes it easy for you to `git reset` it away:

```
...--o--o--o--o   <-- master
      \
       o--o--B
          ^
          |
           \--------- develop
```

and now we can simply forget about `B`, pretend it never existed, shove it off down to the side and start ignoring it:

```
...--o--o--o--o   <-- master
      \
       o--o       <-- develop
           \
            B     [abandoned]
```

A commit that is abandoned like this eventually expires and really does get removed (normally, some time after 30 days have gone by—the abandoned commit is no longer protected by the branch name, but normally remains protected by a *reflog* entry, and these reflog entries eventually expire, after a configurable amount of time, the default being 30 days).

You have another option to get rid of `B`, though.  Just make the same change in reverse.  If you added a line to file `blah.html`, remove that line.  If you changed a word in `main.py`, change it back.  Whatever you did, do the exact opposite.  Then, make a new commit.  Let's call it `U` for Undo:

```
...--o--o--o--o     <-- master
      \
       o--o--B--U   <-- develop
```

The code associated with commit `U`—the working tree—will match the code for the commit right before `B`, because `B` does something bad, and then `U` undoes it.

Making commit `U` is called *reverting*,<sup>1</sup> and there is a command in Git that does this without any extra work on your part: `git revert`.  You give the revert command something to name the bad commit—such as its hash ID, or even just the name `develop` when `B` is the tip commit on branch `develop`—and Git figures out what changed in the bad commit, and makes a reverse commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, Git calls it "reverting".  Others call it "backing out": in Mercurial, the command that "backs out" a commit is `hg backout`.

---

#### The difference between reset and revert

The difference between doing a `reset` to *remove* a bad commit, and doing a `revert` to *add* a new commit that *undoes* the bad one, is precisely that: reverting *adds stuff*.  It *leaves the bad commit in place* and simply adds a new commit that backs out the effect of the bad commit.

#### Git is built around adding new commits

All of Git is built around this whole idea of "adding new stuff".  New commits get added on top of older commits.  Everyone and everything is prepared to deal with this.  *Some* of Git is built to deal with removing commits, but *all* of Git is built to deal with adding them.

If you *have not* pushed a bad commit anywhere else, nor allowed anyone else to fetch it from you, then obviously no one else has it.  This means it is easy to remove the commit from—or at least, abandon it within—your own repository.  Your Git will deal with that.  But if you *have* pushed the commit, or let it get fetched, then someone else has it.  If *you* take it away, you must get *them* to take it away too.  If one other person has it, he may have given it to someone else, and by now there could be thousands of copies of it out there.

In this case, reverting is easier for everyone else.  They are all prepared to get *new* commits, and if you add a new revert commit, they pick it up in the usual way: no fuss, no muss, everyone does what they all do all the time.  So for this purpose revert is usually better.  Of course, it leaves the bad commit behind—but maybe that's even a *good* thing.  It may act as a lesson: "don't try this, it's wrong". :-)

#### If your protected branch only allows new commits

If the protection on the protected branch allows *new* commits to be added, but does not allow "removing" (which is perhaps better called "abandoning") old commits, a revert-and-push will work.

If the protection is something else, perhaps nothing will work.

If the protection can be turned off (temporarily or otherwise), that may allow *both* force-push to abandon a commit, and revert.

Remember that if you force-push, you are racing against anyone else who may also be pushing.  When you force-push, you're telling some other Git to *change* the commit ID where some branch points.  When you do this, you are probably *assuming* that it points to your bad commit right now.  But what if someone else has done a *new* push, *after* your bad commit `B`, that *uses* your commit `B`?  Your force-push will abandon their new commit.  Be sure that's OK—and if not, find some way to make sure it's not going to happen.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>2</sup>This is where `--force-with-lease` comes in, but I'm not going to address that here.